# How to pour values from a R vector into a list object without regarding the list structure including the levels of nesting and names used in the list?

Tags: r, list, vector

Suppose we have a raw list object `list_tmp`, with varying levels of nesting, that looks like the below (at the bottom of the post is code for `list_tmp`.):

```
> list_tmp
$clinic
$clinic$trial
$clinic$trial$patient
     A B
[1,] 0 0
[2,] 0 0


$clinic$result
     C
[1,] 0
[2,] 0


$test
     D
[1,] 0
[2,] 0
```

How can vector values be "poured into" the list object, in the direction rows-columns, without regarding the sublist names or nesting levels? Filling occurs until the earlier of exhausting the vector elements, or until reaching the end of the list. In the full code this is intended for, the number of vector elements will always equal the number of "cells" in the list.

For example, if we have vector `vec <- (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)`, sequentially pouring those vector values into `list_tmp` would result in the following:

```
> list_tmp
$clinic
$clinic$trial
$clinic$trial$patient
     A B
[1,] 1 3
[2,] 2 4


$clinic$result
     C
[1,] 5
[2,] 6


$test
     D
[1,] 7
[2,] 8
```

Code for `list_tmp`:

```
list_tmp <- list(
  clinic = list(
    trial = list(
      patient = matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("A", "B")))
    ),
    result = matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, c("C")))
  ),
  test = matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, c("D")))
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easily done with `relisting`:

```
a <- unlist(as.relistable(list_tmp))
a[seq_along(vec)] <- vec
unclass(relist(a))

$clinic
$clinic$trial
$clinic$trial$patient
     A B
[1,] 1 3
[2,] 2 4


$clinic$result
     C
[1,] 5
[2,] 6


$test
     D
[1,] 7
[2,] 8
```

---

```
vec <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

Comment: When I saw a response from Onyambu, I knew there would be a great answer with powerful, useful functions that are new to me!